# how to make rdlc report for thermal prinnter in c# winforms ,page settings

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have a RDLC report and I am displaying it on the Report Viewer Control in my front end application. I am able to view the report perfectly.
but my problem is that i want to print  report by thermal printer ..so how to set page setting for thermal printer ...plzz give me any suggestion as soon as possible

Comment: So what's the problem with printing by thermal printer?

Comment: page setting for thermal printer . tell me the page size for thermal printer /.??

Comment: well, page size need to match size of actual papers that are put into the printer, which should be in a size that is supported by the printer.  Have you tried standard [paper sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)? For example A4 is 210mm × 297mm.

Comment: ya i tried but thermal needs smaller page size but i dont know what actully is the size of page need for thermal printer

Comment: I guess you need to refer to printer specification then.